Compute integrals in singular integral equation
I'm looking at this paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.07307
and in particular I am interested in eqs. (16) (17), meaning I'd like to check the validity of (16) by insert it in (17).
So I'd like to compute the
$\frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \int_{-B}^{B} d \eta \rho(\eta) \ln (\coth^2 \frac{\theta-\eta}{2}) = \frac{m}{\pi}\cosh \theta \quad \text{(16)}$
with
$\rho(\theta) = \frac{ m \sinh(2B)}{c \sqrt{\sinh^2 B-\sinh^2 \theta}}-2m \sqrt{ \sinh^2B-\sinh^2 \theta} \quad \text{(17)}$
the constant c is obtained by inserting the solution in (17) and it has to be
$c = \frac{ k' K(k)}{E(k)}$
where $E(k), K(k)$ are elliptic integrals of the second kind with $k=1/cosh B$ and $k' =1-k^2$.
Since $\rho$ has two pieces I tried to compute the two integrals separately, adding the principal value for the singularity of the kernel for x=y.
Integrate[Log[ Coth[(x - y)/2]^2] Sqrt[Sinh[B]^2 - Sinh[y]^2, {x, -B, +B},Assumptions -> {Im[B] == 0, y \[Element] Reals}, PrincipalValue -> True]

and
Integrate[Log[ Coth[(x - y)/2]^2] (-2m Sinh[2B] /(Sqrt[Sinh[B]^2 - Sinh[y]^2]), {x, -B, +B},Assumptions -> {Im[B] == 0, y \[Element] Reals}, PrincipalValue -> True]

Unfortunately I don't get any output, just the same input I gave.
I also tried to compare them numerically but it doesn't work
ClearAll[y, B, m, x];
y = 0.7;
B = 1.66;
m = 0.05;
k = 1/Cosh[B] // N
\[Mu] = 2 m EllipticE[k^2]/(k \[Pi]);
k1 = Tanh[B];
c = k1 *EllipticK[k^2]/EllipticE[k^2] // N

primoint = NIntegrate[1/(4 \[Pi]^2)*Log[Coth[(y - x)/2]^2] (Sinh[2 B]/( (c *Sqrt[Sinh[B]^2 - Sinh[x]^2])) - 2 Sqrt[Sinh[B]^2 - Sinh[x]^2]), {x, 0, B}, AccuracyGoal -> 2]

secondoint = NIntegrate[1/(4 \[Pi]^2) Log[Coth[(x - y)/2]^2] (-2 m Sqrt[Sinh[B]^2 -Sinh[x]^2]), {x, -B, B},AccuracyGoal -> 2]

right = (1/\[Pi] )*Cosh[y] // N

but I get primoint=0.319348, secondoint =-0.00538872, right= 0.399533 and they don't match.
Anyone has any idea how to compute these integrals analitically or numerically?
Thanks.

Shouldn't your last code line be right = (m/\[Pi] )*Cosh[y] // N?

Thank you I forgot to cancel m in "secondoint" (I can divide everything by m). But even after that they still don't coincide.

Numerical verification of equation (16) divided by m:
With
c = k1*EllipticK[k^2]/EllipticE[k^2] // N

int1[\[Theta]_?NumericQ] :=   
 NIntegrate[
  1/(4 Pi^2)
    Log[Coth[(\[Theta] - \[Eta])/2]^2]   Sinh[
     2 B]/(( Sqrt[Sinh[B]^2 - Sinh[\[Eta]]^2])) , {\[Eta], -B, B}]  
int2[\[Theta]_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/(4 Pi^2)
    Log[Coth[(\[Theta] - \[Eta])/2]^2] 2 Sqrt[
    Sinh[B]^2 - Sinh[\[Eta]]^2] , {\[Eta], -B, B}]  

equation (16) takes the form int1[\[Theta]]/c - int2[\[Theta]] - 1/Pi Cosh[\[Theta]]
Expression has to vanish for all \[Theta]:
Plot[(int1[\[Theta]]/c - int2[\[Theta]] -1/Pi Cosh[\[Theta]]) , {\[Theta], -B, B}  , PlotRange -> All]


Hope it helps!

Sure it helps, thank you a lot! Are there any chances to compute these integrals analitically to obtain the right hand side of the equation?

@rimbalzando9 No idea how to find analytical solution (you tried it too without success)
